# Open a TOR-Window over SSH

Tags: debian, x11, tor

I use Debian on my vServer.

I use MobaXterm to connect to my vServer. MobaXterm has installed X11 so everything should work.

Now I installed **tor** on the vServer this way:

```
wget https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.0.5/tor-browser-linux64-6.0.5_de.tar.xz
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-6.0.5_de.tar.xz
mv tor-browser_de/* ~/tor
```

I also installed **x-window-system** on the vServer because I read that I have to install this:

```
apt-get install x-window-system
```

Now if I try to launch the browser everything seems fine, but there is no browser that pops up on my screen.

```
tor@test:~/tor$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...
tor@test:~/tor$
```

Am I misunderstanding or do I have to add/change some of the steps I have implemented?

Comment: What ssh command do you use to log in? You probably need the `-X` option: `ssh -X host`.

Comment: I did... But it doesn't work eigther